# I am trying to refresh content based on button clicks

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I would be appreciated if anyone would tell me that how to create backgroung thread when I want to refresh minigame by interval 700 milisecounds - and if the content is changing depend on the button click. Is there a need to creating background thread who is responsible about refreshing?

I tried to refresh content in the same thread where are placed buttons and content. But the buttons are not doing their job - nothing happens.

```
leftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    MainLoopClass.left=true;
    }
});
rightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    MainLoopClass.right=true;
    }
});
turnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
});
startGameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        composite= Observable.interval(700, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).
        observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Consumer(){
            @Override
            public void accept(Object o) throws Exception {
                mainLoop.run();
            }
        });
     }
 });
```

My thinking is that, there in the code will be created new thread after every interval and application will crash

Comment: Can you show what MainLoopClass does?

Comment: I am suggesting read here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: Do you think Timer can be that what I am looking for?

Comment: one of the options is to create `new Thread()` and inside it create loop like `while(true) { \\ do your staff ; sleep(700); }` and that will call your action in background every 0.7 sec. But I suggest to dive into `AsyncTask` and understand that properly

Comment: It becomes unresponsive